# How do I get the Kitty Cannon weapon?

Tags: sunset-overdrive

I used the Kitty Cannon in the [Boo-Boo Roverdrive](http://www.primagames.com/games/sunset-overdrive/walkthrough/sunset-overdrive-act-1-mission-8-boo-boo-roverdrive-kitty-cannon-cutie-kitty) mission. Is it possible to unlock it outside the mission for use in free roam? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently not, since even when you get to use it in "Dawn Of The Rise Of The Fallen Machines", where it's said that Margaret gave Boo-Boo to you, the Kitty Launcher is still just for that section.